# Proxy Error 502 on Apache2 for Reverse Proxy to NodeJs Subdomain App on Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy

**Hello guys**

Im trying to deploy my nodejs api on Digital Ocean, under subdomain https://api.host.com. Its has some path bellow, all starting by /v0.1.

> For example https://api.host.com/v0.1/users

On this droplet the nodejs app is running over http://localhost:3000

At the same droplet i have got other app, a website hosted on Apache and responds at https://host.com it works fine.

Im using Apache for Reverse Proxy make all calls from https://api.host.com/ to http://localhost:3000.

Actually It works only for root path, i mean try to access https://api.host.com/ responds right but when i try to access other path i get error

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: 127.0.0.1:3000v0.1

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at api.host.com Port 443
```

HTTP Status Code: 502 Proxy Error

my vhost looks like...

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
        ...
        ...
        ServerName api.host.com 
        ProxyPass /.well-unknown/ !
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia Full
       <Proxy *>
          Require all granted
      </Proxy>

      ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/ 
      ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/ 
      ...
      ...
 </VirtualHost>
```

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing with an Apache server forwarding requests from a subdomain via a proxy to my nodeJS app listening on port 8080.

I believe that you only need to proxy pass the root to localhost:3000 and the nodeJS app is supposed to handle the routing.

For instance, if you are using express, something like.....

```
app.get('/v.01/users/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile('/v.01/users/index.html'); });
```